# Pandas Swap values of 3 columns with next row

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using a pandas dataframe and want to swap the values of 3 columns [EndLocation, EndDevice, EndPort] in a row with the next row, the next row then becomes the first row.

```
  StartLocation StartDevice StartPort EndLocation EndDevice EndPort LinkType  \
0           DD1     Switch1        P1         AD1   Switch2      P2      MTP   
1          AB11        RU15        P1        AJ11      RU25      P1      NaN   
2           DD2     Switch2        P3         AD2   Switch3      P2      MTP   
3          AB12        RU18        P2        AB11      RU35      P3      NaN   
4           DD3     Switch3        P5         AD3   Switch4      P6      MTP   
5          AB13        RU19        P3        AB11      RU40      P4      NaN
```

expected output:

```
    StartLocation StartDevice StartPort EndLocation EndDevice EndPort LinkType  \
0           DD1     Switch1        P1         AJ11   RU25        P1      MTP   
1          AB11        RU15        P1         AD1    Switch2     P2      NaN   
2           DD2     Switch2        P3         AB11    RU35       P3      MTP   
3          AB12        RU18        P2        AD2    Switch3     P2      NaN   
4           DD3     Switch3        P5        AB11    RU40        P4      MTP   
5          AB13        RU19        P3        AD3   Switch4      P6      NaN
```

`shift()` and `np.roll()` don't fit my use case as this is port mapping and need preserve the start point. Is looping through a dataframe a bad idea?

*Edited for more clarity*

Comment: Is that what your data actually looks like? The column names remain the same based on position? What do you need to do this for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
(
    df.iloc[0::2, 3:6],
    df.iloc[1::2, 3:6],
) = (
    df.shift(-1).iloc[:, 3:6], 
    df.shift(1).iloc[:, 3:6],
)
```

It uses Python's tuple assignment to assign both even and odd rows at the same time.

`df.iloc[0::2, 3:6]` will assign to columns 3, 4 and 5 (`EndLocation`, `EndDevice` and `EndPort`) of the even rows (0, 2 and 4), while `df.iloc[1::2, 3:6]` will assign to the same columns on odd rows (1, 3 and 5.) If you have more than 6 rows, these expressions will keep working.

For the values to assign, we use two shift expressions, one shifting up, for the even rows (1 -> 0, 3 -> 2, 5 -> 4) and the other shifting down for the odd rows (0 -> 1, 2 -> 3 and 4 -> 5), again selecting only columns 3, 4 and 5.

Since Pandas will align the index in an assignment, it will only consider the even or odd rows depending on which expression it's looking at.

Comment: Thanks Filbranden. Works a treat, thanks for the great explanation